How to Extract Nested JSON Array in Redshift and Create a Table with Specific Columns?
I have a table in AWS Redshift with a column called json, which stores a nested JSON object as a string. I need to create a new table with three columns: sid, skill_name, and skill_vdd. The json column contains a nested JSON array under the key rows, and I want to extract the values from this array.
Here is a sample JSON in the json column:
{
    "Id": 888,
    "Command": "uuuu",
    "step": "rows": [
        {"sid": 1515, "skill_name": "jjjj", "skill_vdd": 9999},
        {"sid": 333, "skill_name": "ttt", "skill_vdd": 333}
    ]
}

I've tried using various redshift json functions, but I’m not able to flatten the json
How can I flatten this nested JSON and create a table with the following columns: sid, skill_name, skill_vdd from the json column in Redshift?

I'm going to assume that all entries for this column don't just have 2 values in their array "rows".  In this case you will want to json_parse() this data into a SUPER data type and then "unnest" these array values.  AWS has a good page on unnesting here - https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/query-super.html
This question comes up a lot and I've answered it before here - UNNEST Super data in redshift
If you need help with getting this to work reach out again and show what code you have so far.

Hi Bill, followed this page and it worked for me: https://medium.com/fishtown-analytics/how-to-unnest-arrays-in-redshift-d4fd15f87656

if you have better solution please share here.

Better is relative.  If what you have fully works and is fast enough then you are done, so it's better.  However, Redshift has a built-in method for unnesting arrays that will be much less SQL, faster, and more supportable in the long-run.  It just takes parsing your json into a super type and then following the process laid out in the AWS page.
